# How to filter Chinese punctuation in Scala/Java?

Tags: java, regex, scala

I'm trying to make a language agnostic text parser in Scala/Spark. I was using regex to remove punctuation from large groups of text.

```
list_of_strings.map(_.replaceAll("""[\p{Punct}]"""))
```

However, I find a number of punctuation marks in Chinese text that are not removed. So far I have added `[〝〞。，＂]` to my regex for these characters. Notice that many of these are similar to latin punctuation marks, but not quite the same.

Is there a 'cannonical' function built into Java regex that will allow me to strip punctuation in other languages? Other than Chinese, I'm concerned about Arabic.

Also, I want to ensure that stripped punctuation in one language isn't a critical language component in another. I am not familiar with either the Chinese or Arabic languages, so I'm looking for something premade by a native speaker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to add all those Unicode punctuation chars into the character class. Make the `\p{Punct}` Unicode-aware with the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` or an equivalent `(?U)` embedded flag option:

```
.replaceAll("""(?U)\p{Punct}+""", "")
               ^^^^
```

See the [Scala demo](http://rextester.com/BCXUF20526).

The `+` after `\p{Punct}` removes consecutive punctuation chars is chunks rather than one by one.